# An integral estimate

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is a continuous function on $(0,+\infty)$ and $f\geq 0$. If we have for some positive $\theta$ that
$$\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}f^{\theta}(s)ds\to 0,\quad t\to\infty
$$
then I want to see whether the following is true
$$\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}f(s)ds\to 0,\quad t\to\infty
$$

When $\theta>1$, the answer is yes just by using Horder inequality. But I don't know whether it's right when $0<\theta<1$.

Thanks in advance for any hint.

Comment: I assume $f$ should be nonnegative, else $f^\theta$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: The first line of the question says $f\ge 0$ dude!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no; here's a counterexample for $\theta=1/2$, which you can tweak to make a counterexample for any $0<\theta<1$. The example uses the notation $\phi(x) = x - \lfloor x\rfloor$ for the fractional part of $x$.

Define
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\lfloor x\rfloor^{4/3}, &\text{if } \phi(x) \le 1/\lfloor x\rfloor, \\
0, &\text{if } \phi(x) > 1/\lfloor x\rfloor.
\end{cases}
$$
Then for any (integer) $t$,
$$
\frac1t \int_0^t f(x)\,dx = \frac1t \sum_{j=1}^{t-1} j^{4/3} \frac1j \to \infty
$$
but
$$
\frac1t \int_0^t f^{1/2}(x)\,dx = \frac1t \sum_{j=1}^{t-1} j^{2/3} \frac1j \to 0.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your example, but also note that in your case, $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: True, but it is trivial to convert this function into a closely related continuous function that has the same property. (I meant to make this comment but forgot.)

Comment: Right, I should have  realized this earlier